# Can PL/SQL functions or procedures work with variables inputted by a user during a run?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've been asked to evaluate whether Oracle PL/SQL could be used to perform a re-design of a piece of Fortran code that our organisation has used for years.

This code interacts with our database and cycles through a list of newly registered web users, providing their details to a helpdesk team. The code then asks the helpdesk team if they are happy with the user details, through a Y/N? If Y, the code then proceeds and asks the helpdesk team, again through a series of Y/N statements if certain other statements are true. At the end of every Y/N, there is a write to a row on one or more database tables.

Once it finishes these enquiries with the first user, the code then loops and repeats for the next user in the list.

I know Oracle PL/SQL allows the use in scripts of input variables through `&` and `&&`, but I don't know if the use of these input variable forms is allowed within functions and procedures?

Can someone clarify please for me if `&` and `&&` can be used within PL/SQL code such as functions and procedures?

If not, that's fine - I'll just then have to approach the design process differently.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that won't work in stored procedures. PL/SQL runs on the database server and isn't supposed to interact with users. You can pass values via its parameters (arguments), but that's it.

---

But, if you're on Oracle, consider using its **Application Express** (evaluate it on apex.oracle.com, it is free to register and use). In a matter of *several clicks* (well, not really, but suppose it is so), you can develop a web application which would then be used by users. You'd create a *progress list* navigation which would lead you from one page to another; you'd ask questions and on each press on the "Next page" button you'd store their answer into the database.

So, if you do know some (PL/)SQL, you might do that rather easily.

Illustration:

[image]